# Search a list of names in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a Neo4J database which contains a large number of User objects with each user having fields like name, contact, email etc.

Suppose there is a List which contains values like "aa","bb","cc"...

I want to retrieve all the users whose name contains letters from any of the strings in the above mentioned list

What will be the cypher for it ?

I was able to write the cypher with "=~ (?i).*"+SearchText+".*" but that worked for a single string seach. The problem is when there is a list of strings to search.

I can iterate over each string in the list but that will not be a good idea if the search list contains a large number of search strings.

Answer (score 0):

In 3.0 the `CONTAINS` (see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-where.html#query-where-string) will most likely utilize indexes. For reference here's the pull request for this: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/6233

For doing that in 2.3.x (or earlier) I suggest to use manual indexes together with a `RegexQuery` written in java and deployed as unmanaged extension. For details on this take a look at my blog post at http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2014/10/deep-dive-on-fulltext-indexing-with-neo4j/